# Tracking Google Adwords conversion by class name instead of onclick event

Tags: jquery, google-ads-api

I would like to track clicks on my links with Google Adwords Conversion.

But I have no chance to insert a onclick event in the link (the CMS don't allows this). But I can insert a class name in the link. Could I use a class name instead combined with a little help from jQquery?

Like this

`<a class="onClick" href="http://example.com/your-link">Download now!</a>`

to this string

`<a onclick="goog_report_conversion('http://example.com/your-link')"
href="http://example.com/your-link">Download now!</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery like this:

```
$('.your-class').bind('click', function() {
  goog_report_conversion('http://example.com/your-link');
});
```